# How to place text/content below Navbar in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have created a  header, a nav bar and a footer for my website. And there is a space between those two and when I try to add content it appears just below the header hidden under the nav bar. I used the  tag for content.

Thanks for your help, if you do so.

Here is the code for example.

```
<html>
<body>

<header>
<?php
include 'headfile.php';
echo $logo;
?>
</header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
</ul></nav>

<article>
hello world.
</article>

<footer>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
</ul>
</footer>

</body>
</html>

CSS Part   

article {
background-color: #FFF;
    text-align:justify
}

body {
background-color: #FFF;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav {
   list-style: none;
   width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code here or create an example at http://jsfiddle.net? We can not help you if you don't provide us with your code.

Comment: Please provide your HTML structure here

Comment: Uploading some code will be really helpful

Comment: Have you fixed the position of the navbar?

Comment: Yes, I had done it correctly. But I want to tell you that I don't have any problem with the nav bar but I need to place the content at a correct location.

Comment: No, I understand. By using `position:fixed` you remove the element from the flow of the document so `article` is now top of the tree if you like. Try adding top margin or top padding to the `article` the same height as the navbar and it will pop into place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a style

```
<article style="margin:20px">
```

Comment: You should explain your answer.

Answer (score -2):

first of all, it's:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

second: you need to create containers (divs) for the different content. So if you need to put the content under the nav bar, you could do this:

```
<html>
<body>

<header>
<?php
include 'headfile.php';
echo $logo;
?>
</header>

<nav id='nav-menu'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABC</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id='content-main' class='container'>

</div>






</body>
</html>
```

*I didn't include any styling (yet)

Comment: `nav` is **not** a requirement and your answer does nothing to solve the actual problem. The OP's HTML is perfectly valid on it's face albeit simplistic. It's the CSS that is the issue.

Comment: yeah now it is; before the edit it wasn't, and I had a perfectly valid point. I also don't get the downvotes for this, since the original post was edited after mine. I just handed him some addition; that's all. And you'll never hear me say a `nav` is a requirement; blimmey it was in his original code.